# How to export and import an array with dynamic values in it, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, export, dynamic-arrays

I have an **array** that take dynamically objects as values.
I want to **export it** (with all values, of course) to another js file and **have access to all the elements** (actually objects) of the array from there but, can't find how...
Any ideas will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways
**1)** *Persist the data into a file as json*. When you have all your data collected write it to a `.json` file. Then you can read it in another file and access the data. (Note: only in Node.js environment)

```
// file1.js
const fs = require('fs')
const data = [your_ready_data]
const stringified = JSON.stringify(data)
fs.writeFileSync("store.json", stringified, {encoding: "utf8"});

// file2.json
const dataString = fs.readFileSync("store.json", { encoding: "utf8" });
const data = JSON.parse(dataString) // 
// ...
```

**2)** *send as argument*.

```
//file1.js
const mainFunction = (list) => {
  //....
}


// file2.js
import mainFunction from 'file1.js'
const collectDate = () => {
  //....
  const data = [your_ready_data]
  
  mainFunction(your_ready_data)
  //....
}
```